# How to change save path

Tags: java, file

I am created xml docs, but they are by default saving to the project folder in netbeans projects.

I have a file path that I need them to be saving to instead:

```
public static String XML_DIR = "c:/Users/ericrea/Desktop/413final";
```

Here is the code I have written so far, I tried using the `f.renameto()` method, but it won't accept a string file location:

```
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(testDoc);

        File f;
        f=new File(emp.getId() + ".xml");

        f.createNewFile();

        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(f);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(ps);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
            .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: @Eric "I tried using the f.renameto() method, but it won't accept a string file location:"  There is no such method as `renameto()`.  Did you mean `renameTo()`?  Note the actual method accepts a `File`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
File f = new File (XML_DIR, emp.getID() + ".xml");
```

That will match the

> File(String parent, String child)
>   Creates a new File instance from a
>   parent pathname string and a child
>   pathname string.

constructor

or

```
File f = new File (XML_DIR + emp.getID() + ".xml" );
```

That will use the

> File(String pathname)
>             Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname
>   string into an abstract

pathname.
constructor for the File object.  Either one should give you the result you're looking for.

More info on the File object [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html).